# Algorithm to convert a straight skeleton of an orthogonal poygon into an orthogonal straight skeleton

Tags: algorithm, geometry

Consider the definition of an orthogonal polygon as a closed curve in 2 dimensions where all edges are aligned to two orthogonal axes.
The straight skeleton of such polygon is a set of straight-line segments that follow a property that every point in the skeleton is the same distance of the polygon edges.

This is an orthogonal polygon with a straight skeleton.

[image: Orthogonal polygon with a straight skeleton in red]

What I need is an algorithm that takes this straight skeleton and approximates it using only orthogonal lines.

One example of approximation that is not ideal, but is something I would accept as a starting point, would be this skeleton:

[image: Orthogonal approximation of straight skeleton]

Are there algorithms that achieve similar goals in the literature?

Comment: Well, the nature of the straight skeleton is that convex corners are bisected, which of course means that the edges are not axis-aligned. So what property/ies of the straight skeleton are you trying to retain in your output? You’ve shown us something that’s “not ideal”, but haven’t described what you think of as “ideal”.

Comment: @Sneftel depending on the width of the polygon, my application may require additional orthogonal lines to cover more of the shape. Please disregard this added complexity.

Comment: That doesn’t answer my questions.

Comment: The property of the straight skeleton that I am trying to retain is a one-dimensional structure that "resembles" the original two-dimensional polygon.

Comment: You could compute a straight skeleton, and then replace diagonal line segments with "stair steps" at whatever granularity you want.